# Android application project not generating default files?

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi i am using eclipse indigo and i have downloaded the adt plugin as said in the documents on the site http://developer.android.com . I also have installed the android SDK. After this when i am creating the android application project it is not generating any default files. All the application folders are empty. My java runtime is 1.7. I have downloaded the latest Android SDK which is there on site. As there are no files generated in the application i was not able to run "hello world". I am doing exactly what is said in the document on android developer site. Kindly help me fix this? what could be the problem?

Comment: Indigo is an outdated version of Eclipse. Try downloading the ADT Bundle as described here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: this is quite normal on eclipse try clean build and restarting eclipse.

Comment: hi Maveric I have done as said in the link you  have provided. It is not working. That is the reason i have landed here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is but 64 bit ADT-SDK is not working on 64 bit windows-7 machine but at the same time 32 bit ADT-SDK is working fine without any problem. I am not sure why this is happening. I thought first my download got tampered but it is not. 64 bit does not work.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but I'm on a 32bit System and with the 32bit version it is not working.
This is driving me crazy but I'll let you know if I find a solution.